# Please help me identify this 'techno' font

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone know the name of this font, or the name of the style/category where I could look for similar ones?

[image: Need help finding a similar or same font]

Comment: It appears to simply be 3D modeling of shapes. How do you know it's a "font"?

Comment: Where did you find the image Kreo? if we know the source, it may help the community identify the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) has an online font matching tool, "WhatTheFont", which can help you find a font given a bitmap of a couple of characters. Unfortunately 2 characters is too few to get a good match (unless the image is very clear and sharp). I've found good matches for 8 to 10 characters, for instance.
For your question WhatTheFont doesn't give relevant fonts, but the tool may be useful for similar questions from other users.

Answer (score 1):

Check Techno Various fonts

[Techno Various Fonts](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=304&page=1&text=RZ)

[image]

Above you have some similar fonts :

[HFF Eye Sore](http://www.dafont.com/hff-eye-sore.font?text=RZ)

[image]